# How to link wasi-libc with shared memory flag?

Tags: clang, webassembly

I want to import shared memory in my WASM module and trying to link my object files all compiled with `-matomics` and `-mbulk-memory`, and wasi-libc `-lc`, `lc++` and `-lc++abi` libraries. But getting an error:

> wasm-ld: error: --shared-memory is disallowed by errno.o because it was not compiled with 'atomics' or 'bulk-memory' features.

As i understand wasm-ld links some libc object files, compiled without flags above, so it can't be linked. How can i provide these flags to linker? Or need to build wasi-libc from source with these flags?

Answer (score 1):

Problem has been solved by specifying `--no-check-features` flag at linking.

Answer (score 0):

wasi-libc does not support shared memory or multi-threading today.   If you want to try to make something work you would, at minimum, need to recompile the the core libraries (libc, compiler-rt, libcxx, libcxxabi) with the `-pthread` compiler flag.

If you want to use mutli-threading with WebAssembly as of today (2021) the only reasonable option it use emscripten and its Web Worker-based multi-threading approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i have solved the problem by adding `--no-check-features` flag to wasm-ld. I'm not using C-level multi-threading, but JS SharedArrayBuffer. I'm creating multiple instances from WASM module and they are using shared buffer from different workers finely.

Comment: How do you plan to deal part of the libc that normally require locking, e.g. `malloc`?   If you are planning on using malloc/free to manage you memory its not safe to use the version of libc shipping in wasi-sdk (since its built without locking).  Just FYI.

If you are assigning each module its own distinct non-overlapping part of the memory then you should be ok.

Comment: I'm allocating all memory from main worker before spawning workers. And workers are operating with same memory regions, but not allocating memory. And there are no problems now. There are some builtin WASM atomic functions, so i think i will try to use it for other cases.

Comment: maybe you know other ways to link standard libraries to WASM code? I have tried to link clang libc/libc++, but it failed, because i was able to use only its headers but not binaries since it is compiled not to WASM bytecode, obviously. Wasi-libc works fine, but i'm wondering is it a right way to use standard libraries in browser?

Comment: If you are using wasi-libc and you link with clang++ it will include libc++ by default.   libc++ is part of wasi-sdk, just like libc (and libcompiler-rt and libc++abi).   You should not need to explicitly link any of these libraries, the clang/clang++ driver will do that for you.